# Reading varbinary from JDBS table (Phoenix) as double value

Tags: sql, apache-phoenix

I have a atble in Phoenix as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE VROC_SENSORDATA (
    NODE_ID VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    DATA_TIMESTAMP BIGINT NOT NULL,
    YYYYMMDD UNSIGNED_INT,
    "HOUR" UNSIGNED_TINYINT,
    "MINUTE" UNSIGNED_TINYINT,
    "SECOND" UNSIGNED_TINYINT,
    DATA_QUALITY FLOAT,
    DATA_VALUE VARBINARY,
    CONSTRAINT VROC_SENSORDATA_PK PRIMARY KEY (NODE_ID,DATA_TIMESTAMP)
) ;
```

The column name DATA_VALUE is VARBINARY and included double values

I am using Spark and then give a JDBC (SQL ) query as

```
SELECT *
FROM VROC_SENSORDATA WHERE NODE_ID='05535dbe-1aca-3789-aa16-adbd95ed2925';
```

I will get results like bellow

```
+------------------------------------+--------------+--------+----+------+------+------------+-------------------+
|NODE_ID                             |DATA_TIMESTAMP|YYYYMMDD|HOUR|MINUTE|SECOND|DATA_QUALITY|DATA_VALUE         |
+------------------------------------+--------------+--------+----+------+------+------------+-------------------+
|05535dbe-1aca-3789-aa16-adbd95ed2925|1455839492468 |20160219|7   |51    |32    |100.0       |[33 36 33 33 2E 30]|
|05535dbe-1aca-3789-aa16-adbd95ed2925|1455839492734 |20160219|7   |51    |32    |100.0       |[32 38 36 35 2E 30]|
|05535dbe-1aca-3789-aa16-adbd95ed2925|1455839492967 |20160219|7   |51    |32    |100.0       |[34 35 31 36 2E 30]|
|05535dbe-1aca-3789-aa16-adbd95ed2925|1455839493233 |20160219|7   |51    |33    |100.0       |[32 34 39 39 2E 30]|
```

I need to get the exact double value .Is ther anyway to convert above to double when I use the SQL query?